# Android google map not exact coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello i am developing my own map locator. But it doesn't give a exact coordinates. I already tried Google Map to locate my current location it gives me the right location from where i was.

In Google Map Application
[image]

But on my App
[image]

I don't know why is my application doesn't give me the exact location as GOOGLE MAP App.

Did i miss something?
Here's my google map initialization

`  int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

```
        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fgmMain);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Zoom in the Google Map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


                // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
                db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                DBUser duser = db.getUser().get(0);

                Marker mark = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .title(duser.get_name() + " - " + Build.MODEL)
                                .snippet("Location: " + latLng.toString() + " @ " + gTime)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(MapIcon("myphone")))
                                .anchor(0.5f, verticalAnchor)
                );

                Log.d("Current Location", latLng.toString());

                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

        }`
```

Manifest XML
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.package.phonelocate.phonelocator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

`
Can i get the same result as google map app?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```